# Remove RevealViewController PanGestureRecognizer from Login Screen

Tags: xcode6, uistoryboard, sidebar, uistoryboardsegue, swrevealviewcontroller

I have implemented SidebarDemo project from [Appcode](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) and then modified Storyboard with Login screen, now when I start my application Login Screen come which is correct and I dont want Pan Gesture on Login screen and I am trying to remove it from code below

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

}


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.navigationController.view.gestureRecognizers) {
        [self.navigationController.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }

     self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

//    NSArray* gestureRecognizers = [self.navigationController.navigationBar gestureRecognizers];
//    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in gestureRecognizers) {
//        if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
//            gestureRecognizer.enabled =  YES;
//            
//            break;
//        }
//    }

    //[self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer removeTarget:self action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

}
```

But Pan Gesture is still swiping on Login but when I go to internal screen and comes on Login Screen so it get remove, but why isnt it removing from the first time of application start

My Storyboard Image as below

[image: Story board]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, your login screen shouldn't be the front view of SWRevealViewController, cause you don't need a sidebar in it. Create a modal segue from your login view controller to the reveal view controller and perform it when user has logged in successfully. Delete the segue from reveal view controller to login's navigation controller, but create one from reveal to survey choice (don't forget to set it's identifier to sw_front and embed survey choice controller in navigation controller). Create segues from sidebar's logout button to login's navigation view controller and perform it when user wants to logout.
To be more clear, I add photo of my own app, that has similar thing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3nWe.png